# When someone opts out via an email, the last updated and modified by do not get changed? Should they?

Tags: civimail, contacts

If you go in and update the contact and make them opt out, there is a log entry and the modified date gets updated on civicdm_contact.  If the contact does it via an email link there is no change to the modified date and no log entry.  Shouldn't it behave the same way no matter how the update is done?

Comment: Can I ask if this is a 'Is this only happening to me?' question or 'Why doesn't CiviCRM do this?' question? (Sorry, StackExchange ettiquette remains a mystery to me, and it's possible this has gone unanswered because it verges on requiring an opinion - but I figure if you're actually wondering if there's an error, you might want reassuring that it's not you, it's CIviCRM)

Comment: I think you can ask questions like those.  If the question is inappropriate someone will suggest how to make it appropriate.  This question might be asking for an opinion but I think it's more asking is this a bug or am I missing something.  Since no one expressed any interest in this, I figured this doesn't really bother anyone and so is of little importance to the broad community.

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to check what kind of response you were looking for.